# how to associate private key with a certificate in keychain

Tags: iphone, keychain, codesignkey

I just downloaded iphone sdk 4. when I try to install on the device I get

> "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone
>   Developer' doesn't match any valid
>   certificate/private key pair in the
>   default keychain"

I have gone through the process of creating a provisioning profile and cert through iphone Development Provisioning Assistant. However, after installing the profile and cert the assistant asks to check whether public and private key are paired (surprisingly, it shows a pic of what seems to be a private key and cert being paired, i.e. the cert is 'under' private key in hierarchical terms. This is not the case in my keychain. Public key, private key and cert are there but there doesn't seem to be any associations.

Does anyone know how to pair a private key and certificate in keychain please this please?

ps. I have checked this thread but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

[iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-f)

Comment: how did you install your cetificate

Comment: i think i followed the steps from the link, i.e. delete keychain entry etc. and re-do the whole process.

Comment: i hope you have not downloaded the certificate itself. You just need to download the provisioning profile. Installing it installs the cert. and associates with key pair.

Answer (score 3):

[I wrote a wiki page (here)](http://www.manyfriends.com/wiki/iphone/index.php/Create_an_ad-hoc_provisioning_profile#Export_the_Certificate.2Fkey-pair_matching_the_Ad-hoc_profile) that describes how to export your certificate and private key pair.  It's intended for my iOS development clients to send me their ad-hoc, but I believe it will solve your problem, too.  The key is to make sure that you export the certificate and private-key *PAIR* all in one go -- not as two separate exports.

Hopefully, the screenshot near the bottom of that page will help out.