# Certificate signing problem prevents testing my app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, deployment

I been invited in the Apple Developer, and I downloaded the certificate that was made for me, also the provisioning profile and finally the WWDR intermediate certificate. I installed all of them and when I build and run my app to the device it gives me the following error:

> [BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

This is for a graduation project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this post. It may help resolve your issue.

[iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-f)

Comment: thanks I saw the link and the way the suggest as deleting everything from the website I can't do it since I am only a member of the team

Comment: You may wish to contact your team manager and double check your UDID to make sure they have the correct device provisioned and have them recreate your certificate, and profile for you.