# Xcode won't recognize my new provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, xcode-organizer

My app's development provisioning profile expired a couple of weeks ago, so I went to the provisioning portal to get a fresh new one. After obtaining it, I visited the Xcode Organizer, removed the expired profile from my devices as well as my Mac, then imported the new profile. Xcode installs the profile onto my devices immediately, and my app runs again on the devices.

The problem is that while the Organizer is able to see the new profile and install it as normal, the IDE gets confused between the old one and the new one. Every time I try to build the app, it fails immediately. The error console tells me that Xcode can't find the old profile, because the GUID listed belongs to the old one. That's strange; I thought Xcode would've been aware of the new profile by now.

I've tried removing the new profile from my devices and my Mac, then reinstalling the profile. Doesn't work, Xcode is still trying to look for the old one. I've also tried selecting a different profile to make Xcode forget the old one, then selecting the new one. I've even tried manually entering the GUID of the new one in the **Other** choice. Yet Xcode still insists on looking for the old profile, which by now is already gone from my Mac.

How do I convince Xcode that I've generated a new provisioning profile for my app for it to use?

Comment: Follow the steps from this link. The steps that has 33 up clicks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-f/2241624#2241624 Good luck.

Comment: The answer to this question (see accepted answer below) is still valid for Xcode 4.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**tl;dr:** turns out I simply had to edit the project file manually to tell Xcode of the new profile. Now, I don't know *why* I had to manually update the project file. Perhaps I did something wrong during the process of importing the new profile to Xcode, so it didn't realize my new profile had come in. Or the file system choked midway and Xcode wasn't able to update itself. Oh well.

Now for the <del>fun</del> technical part:

> **IMPORTANT:** As with anything else that involves modifying files you shouldn't be modifying: **make sure to back up your `.xcodeproj` bundle and/or your entire Xcode project, or make sure your Xcode project is kept in proper version control**. You don't want to mess up and cause Xcode to stop building your project onto your device, without anything to fall back on.

I peeked into the contents of my app's `.xcodeproj` bundle (Xcode is not running at this time). To view these, open your project folder in Finder, then Control-click on your `.xcodeproj` file and choose **Show Package Contents**:

```
Breeze.xcodeproj/
  Daniel.mode1v3
  Daniel.pbxuser
  project.pbxproj
```

Then opened `project.pbxproj` in a text editor (it's text, not binary), and looked around for build configuration information.

There's a section labeled `/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */` (which you can find using your editor's search function). It's a list of entries, each of which represents a code-signing configuration for a given profile in a given build configuration.

Here's information about the profile I use to sign my binary for development:

```
1D6058940D05DD3E006BFB54 /* Debug */ = {
    isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
    buildSettings = {
        ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
        "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Developer: Daniel Tan (XXXXXXXXXX)";
        COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
        GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO;
        GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
        GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
        GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = Breeze_Prefix.pch;
        GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42;
        INFOPLIST_FILE = "Breeze-Info.plist";
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 4.0;
        PRODUCT_NAME = "Breeze";
        "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "36F99F3E-805F-47A7-95D4-FF8324711CBE";
        SDKROOT = iphoneos;
    };
    name = Debug;
};
```

Of note is this line:

```
"PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "36F99F3E-805F-47A7-95D4-FF8324711CBE";
```

That's the GUID reported by the build error; the identifier of my old, expired provisioning profile.

All I had to do was replace it with the GUID of the new profile:

```
"PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "E6E6369E-FD58-4886-9C3A-72C9DAE36501";
```

I open my project in Xcode again, and now my app builds and installs on my devices successfully, using the new provisioning profile.

Comment: Another thing: I don't know if the format has changed at all in Xcode 4, because I haven't started using it yet. This answer applies to Xcode 3.

Comment: As noted by Arkaaito's comment on my question, the same thing applies to Xcode 4.

Comment: How do I find the GUID of the certificate?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: The Organizer tells you this when you view it in the Provisioning Profiles section.

Comment: That was a nice trick... Thanks! BTW to find ID for provisioning Profile, you have to follow steps here: https://coderwall.com/p/znqi-w/finding-the-uuid-of-an-iphone-provisioning-profile

Answer (score 15):

Here's how I did it in Xcode 4:

1. Select Don't Code Sign from Project > Build Settings > Code Signing
2. Clean the build
3. Build it again - should show an error like "this stuff needs signing"
4. Choose the new profile from the Code Signing
5. Rebuild

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfectly and no need to change anything directly in a file.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix this error by changing it to "Don't Code Sign" in Code Signing Identity.  Build, and you get the error "code signing is required for product type ...blah...".  Then go back and select the right profile.  Build and all good.  This happened to me because my certificate expired and I renewed it.  In addition to the above I also had to remove the old certificate from my keychain, and the Organizer.

Comment: Removing the old certificates was the deal maker for me, thx!

Answer (score 1):

1. Close de xcode
2. edith with texmate, youtproject.xcodeproj
3. Find this line `"PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "E8DEEBA3-FE0A-419F-9F7E-258572D55807";`
4. Erase
5. Restart xcode build & archive for enterprise

Answer (score 1):

To add to the [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291464/770326), you can use the lovely [xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) gem to help with stuff like this. Note, it does convert your OpenStep `key = value;` -style plist to XML. Note: I have found that Xcode changes it back if you make project file changes in Xcode later. Either style of file builds fine either in Xcode or from the command line. For a sample of how I use it

```
project = Xcodeproj::Project.new('Foo.xcodeproj')
csi_key = 'CODE_SIGNING_IDEDNTITY'
project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |conf|
    conf.build_settings[csi_key] = 'iPhone Developer: Cool Dood (XYZ123)' unless conf.build_settings[csi_key] == nil
  end
end
```

Here's a gist of how I use it: https://gist.github.com/82times/5594887

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem was:

1. Download your new provisioning profile
2. Double click the provisioning profile to install it
3. Go to the following directory on your mac:
   `/Users/<your.username>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
4. Find the old provisioning profile that you no longer want (but keeps showing up in Xcode). This may come in handy for this step: https://github.com/chockenberry/Provisioning
5. Delete it
6. Completely exit Xcode
7. Reopen Xcode
8. You should now be able to select your new provisioning profile

Answer (score 1):

Most answers did not work for me as they seem to be for older versions.

For Xcode 8.3.2:

1. Xcode->Preferences->Accounts
2. Select Apple ID
3. Double-click your Team
4. Click the '+' dropdown in the bottom left to "Create a certificate"
5. Choose iOS Development
6. Click 'Done'

After doing this I was able to tell Xcode was using the latest profile by clicking the 'i' info icon next to "Xcode Managed Profile" under Targets->General->Signing and confirming that the 'Created' date reflected the new one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with XCode 5, when my developer certificate expired, I ran into this issue. I manually downloaded the new certificate and new provisioning profile. I added the certificate to the keychain and the provisioning profile to the devices in organizer.

However, XCode kept complaining that I cannot sign the app. I figured that in XCode 5 preferences, it still displayed the old provisioning profile and it didn't refresh to the the new one despite numerous reloads that I did there.

Eventually, I used iPhone Configuration Utility to delete the old provisioning profile and add the newly downloaded provisioning profile. After code signing worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that double clicking on the downloaded provisioning profile would place it into xCode Organizer Archive, but that just wouldn't work for me. The following steps finally worked for me.

1. Open xCode
2. Go to Product -> Destination -> iOS Device
3. Go to Product -> Archive