# No profile for team 'RGNG4KKEAN' matching 'PD_Prod_18_March' found:

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ios-app-signing

> Showing Recent Messages
>   :-1: No profile for team 'RGNG4KKEAN' matching 'PD_Prod_18_March' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'RGNG4KKEAN/PD_Prod_18_March'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor. (in target 'PocketDeals')

I have taken over a project from a developer for a client. I am unable to release the iOS app due to this above issue. I found it difficult to find a solution due to most people having a different circumstance (first time building an app, etc).

- Under signing in the build setting tabs I have changed to the correct
  information.
- I have attached my Developer Apple ID under accounts in the
  preferences window
- Additionally I have tried restarting Xcode after making these
  changes.
- I am able to build to simulator but not to my own device.
- Tried this in terminal

  > rm ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/*.mobileprovision

Now trying this post which sounds similar

[Xcode won't recognize my new provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291463/xcode-wont-recognize-my-new-provisioning-profile)

By following the link I was able to manually edit RGNG4KKEAN out of Xcode. I now have it just down this problem..

> Showing Recent Messages
>   :-1: PocketDeals has conflicting provisioning settings. PocketDeals is automatically signed, but provisioning profile PD_Prod_18_March has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor. (in target 'PocketDeals')

**FINAL EDIT:**
I have finally solved this myself, I eventually got automatic signing to work. The big thing was pulling out a different project and comparing information, not sure which thing finally allowed my app to build on my real phone. I removed all traces of the old provisioning file, corrected package names, set debug to the correct settings, etc.

Comment: See my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573190/341994 You still have a manually specified profile in your build settings

Comment: I was trying to wipe the old one out. Trying your method but I only see two Code Signing Identities, and on step three if I am at the right spot in the build section I can only choose "automatic" or "other". Other leads to a blank box..

Comment: I was able to make step two work, I believe I misunderstood it. Still haven't fixed my overall issue though