# Help with provisioning profiles for coworker's iMac

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I'm not super familiar with setting up the provisioning profiles and CSR for iPad development.  I joined a new company trying to do this and the iMac I'm using used to belong to someone else (not sure if that matters).  I don't know if he ever tested on the device or not.  They gave me access to the iOS developer site.  I received my CSR through the website and installed it in keychain.  In My Certificates, I do see my new certificate and it is green and says Certificate valid.

I see that there is already a TeamProvisioning profile on the device for the app when I log into the developer's portal.  However, in Xcode, I have this error when I build to the device:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

And in Xcode organizer, it says:

```
Xcode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain.
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a machine you're not familiar with, I'd opt to go through all of the steps in the [Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html) section of the iOS Development Guide. This will help you double check to make sure that everything is lined up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Apple Developer signing certificate and get it into the keychain.
Go to your developer portal
Renew the provisioning profile for invalid profile
or you can do in your xcode->Organizer and click on refresh button there

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough I had a hard time with this just yesterday. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-f/2241624#comment-8223210) should do the trick. Look at Louie's answer.