# Can't get Xcode to see my distribution certification? Code sign error: The identify 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile?

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I can't seem to get Xcode to see my distribution certification? Code sign error: The identify 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile?

So:

- In IOS Provisioning Portal

  - have a distribution certificate that is NOT expired
  - have a Team Provisioning Profile (not really sure of how this is used)
- Have downloaded the distribution cert and double clicked on it and imported it to keychain
- Goto Xcode - created a distribution profile
- Under Product / BuildSettings / Distribution line item => If I click on "iPhone Distribution" there is no matches that occur....

If I can see the distribution certificate in KeyLink shouldn't this be the trigger for Xcode to be able to see this?

Am I missing something / how could I fix so I can press ahead with uploading app...

thanks

Comment: did you press "always allow"?, i think there's a bug with 'always allow' button and you need to click just 'allow'

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563364/how-can-i-add-private-key-to-the-distribution-certificate/34733699

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem. I have created a list of step by step instructions on how to fix it. Hope it helps.

[iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be/2241624#2241624)

Comment: I've just learned that you will see that error, "a valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found...", if your certificate has expired.  Therefore, one remedy is to renew your certificate and provisioning profile.

Answer (score 4):

Just having the certificate on its own wont help. You need to check if you also have the private key associated with it.

Click on Keychain access on your Mac, and go to the Certificates part and check if your certificate comes with your private key. If it doesnt, then you might have to get your private key.

You can have a look at this tutorial:

http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html

Comment: I have explained the answer above. The link is only for the developer or anyone to gain an idea of the exact steps and maybe find where they went wrong probably. @ShariqueAbdullah