# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: xxx (zzz)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios-simulator

Please help, I've spent 4 hours deleting and re-creating keys and provisioning profiles, trying to get my iOS 5 app to build in xcode for deployment to ipads. I'm using in-house distribution. A few months ago I went through all the same hell but finally got it working. Trying everything I tried before, it just doesn't work now. I'm getting this error in xcode: "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: xxx (zzz)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain".

Everything appears correct in Keychain Access and Xcode. In Xcode it shows my Provisioning Profile as Valid.

I have gone through all the steps (multiple times) here: [iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be)

I have deleted all keys and profiles, created all new, created new App IDs (I have a ton of these now that I can't delete). I've been through numerous online articles and they all say to try the same thing: delete, re-create, and reinstall keys and profiles. That's just not working for me.

Please help, I'm at wits end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just thought I'd chime in incase in your frustration you haven't restarted xcode.

I had a similar issue a couple of days ago as I was building up a new laptop.  I had everything in place as I thought it should be but xcode would give me the same error.

After closing and restarting Xcode, the error went away and everything worked as expected.  I'm using xcode 4.4.

Comment: Thank you. One other question, after deleting all keys and profiles, and re-creating stuff, I have no Public key in Keychain...only a Private key. Could this be causing my problem? I can't figure out how to create a Public key, and I don't even know what that would be for.

Comment: I think the public key is not needed because I got it working by upgrading to the latest xcode. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to remove all references to former provisioning profiles in your project's project.pbxproj file. Here is a [short tutorial](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found/) on how to do that (the error message in that tutorial does not exactly match your's but it might be worth a try):

Comment: I'll try this and report back.