# How to overcome error Valid Signing Identity Not found for Provision profile in Organizer in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be)

I have created the app id on my apple iOS provisioning portal  for my app.

When i am going to create provision profile for my device and drag it to `Xcode Organizer` is showing error "`Valid Signing Identity not found`". 
How to overcome this error?

I have revoke my apple certificate. key chain access show my apple certificate valid.

After revoking my certificate i got email from apple that say

```
(Dear User,

You have revoked your APS Development Certificate and it is no longer valid. Please note that all Provisioning Profiles that included this certificate are now invalid and will require regeneration for future use.

Best regards,

Apple Developer Program Support)
```

What is error in my provisioning profile of device if any know solution plz reply

Key chain Access screen [image]

XCODE Organizer screen [image]

Comment: please share your keyChain screen shot

Comment: Sorry i can,t upload image on stack overflow as i am new user

Comment: do you have arrow sign in front of your certificate? mean are you able to expand you certificate,,

Comment: No i don't have arrow sign in front of my certificate. what does it indicate?

Comment: just delete your certificate from key chain as well as from apple then req for new certificate.. go KeyChain -> KeyChainAccess -> Certificate Assistant -> Req for new Certificate.   Then go to provisioning portal, submit you CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -> then create certificate -> then refresh -> download -> then dragDrop in your keyChain

Comment: Hey thanks Valid Signing Identity not found problem is solve. But i have come to new error Provision Profile does not match in code signing identity of XCODE target.i have valid  Provision Profile in Organizer. why this happen?

Comment: is your problem solved with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little bit confusing. You have to use the Keychain Access app on your mac to generate an certificate which you upload to the iOS provisioning portal. ( generates privat - public keys)

For me the best tutorial about this topic is from the [ray wenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)
Also check the second part of this tutorial.

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

create provisioning profile using the newly created certificate. Don't use the revoked certificate.

Comment: I have created new provisioning profile for new certificate though it give erroe

Answer (score 0):

Here is FAQ related to APPLE certificates,
https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make following notes.

1. Clear or Delete all Developer and Distribution Certificates and Provisioning Profiles.
2. Go to Keychain Request New Certificate.
3. Go to Developer Account Revoke old Certificate and Add new Created Certificate.
4. Create New App id and Provisioning Profile.
5. Add this provisioning profile to Xcode.
6. Then Build and Run your App.