# iOS development, certificate/private key pair, valid identity not found

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-provisioning, profiles

I just updated mac system software, now I cannot build onto my devices. When I try to build I get this error: The identity `iPhone Developer: my name (XXXXXXXX)` doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains.

In the organizer I get: `"valid identity not found"` warning for all of my provisioning profiles. I looked in the dev center and saw that I had no certificate so I generated a new one, and double clicked it to install. I think it installed but I have the same error. DO I need to remove something, or generate more provisions?

**RESOLVED:** Look for the Refresh button on the bottom right of the Organizer window. Tapping this will download and install the necessary certificates and notify if they are not generated on the dev center.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be

Comment: @Deepesh thanks. The Refresh button on the bottom right was the key as it automatically checks for all of the certificates. Turns out I needed to generate a distribution cert, now all is good.