# No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When i am selecting the iphone device and build,it is showing the error for xamarin.ios

Error   555 No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you check the bundle id of the app.? provisioning profile by which you signing your app.? and more important to check for the UDID added to that particular provisioning profile in developer.apple.com...

Comment: any news on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to reinstall the certificates and provisioning profiles:

- go to the Apple [Member Center](http://developer.apple.com) and **download** all **certificates** and **provisioning profiles**
- **save** them somewhere you can access theme like on desktop
- **double-click** all of them, certificates and profiles
- this will bring up Xcode and the Keychain
  **close** Keychain as you won't need it anymore
- in Xcode, go to **Build Settings** to verify the profiles were added correctly
- **set** the Developer Code Signing Identity to your profile

All the important files are reinstalled now. Maybe that will fix your problem.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check and install the correct certificate with provisioning profile from apple developer. The following links can help you-

[iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be)

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/