# iOS application provisioning profile error , profile not associated

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I need to figure out the reason for this error while installing an application on iOS devices. Here what error says while installation :

[image]

I don't have any expertise on iOS development. Please explain the issue and resolution if can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a new provision profile and install. Your provision profile has some issue. You added wrong provision profile in codeSigning

Comment: @Shruti : can you elaborate the steps in a bit detail or share some links , that will be of great help.

Comment: @theJango Try to see this link..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be

Comment: Does the app identifier in your provisioning profile match what you've assigned your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1.Go to Project setting.In left panel see there is Targets.

2.Clicked on (your Project name)Tests.

3.Go to Info. There assign the proper Bundle identifier.

4.Go to build setting->Code Signing

5.Here set the Code Signing Identity and Provision Profile (Make Sure you select correct provision profile)

6.Clean the Build.